# Convert a file into binary buffer in C?

Tags: c, file, buffer

I'm just starting in c/c++. I'm able to write a file from binary :

```
FILE *myFile= fopen("/mnt/music.mp3", "ab+"); // Doesn't exist

fwrite(binaryBuffer, sizeOfBuffer, 1, myFile);
```

All I want is to get a new "binaryBuffer" from "myFile"

How I can do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Pick a language C and C++ are two languages with different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fread` function, which works just like `fwrite`:

```
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // declare a buffer
fread(buffer, length, 1, file); //read length amount of bytes into buffer
```

If you don't know how many bytes to read you can seek to the end of the file to find the length.

(If you read from the same file you just wrote to you will want to rewind)
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/